# Am I thinking about Redis::throttle correctly?

Tags: laravel, throttling

I'm using `Redis::throttle` in my laravel application to limit requests to various web services, but let's just say Amazon for example.

If the Amazon docs say that a particular user can use a particular endpoint with the following leaky bucket limitation: allowed 40 request, with a new request being allowed every half second after the initial 40.

Then I would make my `Redis::throttle` look like this:

```
    $key = 'Amazon|'.$requestType.'|'.$user->id;
    Redis::throttle($key)->allow(40)->every(20)->then(function () {
        // Job logic...
    });
```

Allow 40 requests every 20 seconds seems like how the leaky bucket is defined. But is that right?

Because the alternative, I guess, is just me allowing 2 requests per second

```
Redis::throttle($key)->allow(2)->every(1)
```

But that wouldn't allow bursts of 40.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at how the information is stored when you do `Redis::throttle($key)->allow(40)->every(20)` and discovered the following:

It stores two time stamps, a 'start' and an 'end', in seconds. 'start' will be the timestamp when the first time 'throttle' is called on that key, and 'end' will be the start timestamp + whatever value is in `->every()`

```
1) "start"
2) "1579168555"
3) "end"
4) "1579168575"
5) "count"
6) "1"
```

So, in this case, start will be 1579168555 and end will be 1579168575

And then it also stores a count, which increments on every subsequent call, until the timestamp is passed, and then it deletes the previous start/end/count and starts a new one.

The problem with this, in regards to leaky bucket, is it would actually allow you to do the following:

- Make 1 request at, say, timestamp 1579168555
- Wait 15 seconds and then make 39 requests at timestamp 1579168570
- Wait 6 more seconds, and now the Throttle key is cleared, and now you can make 40 request

But the last two steps would be 79 requests in a short space of time, which is not allowed.

So I'm actually better off doing something like `Redis::throttle($key)->allow(2)->every(1)` and now allowing bursts. The `throttle` interface does not fully implement leaky bucket logic, but it allows you to throttle it in a way that will at least keep you compliant with the leaky bucket.